# Can a question be a duplicate of a future question?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/29266/28015) was recently marked as a duplicate, but when I reviewed it, I noticed that the question it was supposedly a duplicate of was asked nearly a year later. It seems, however that there would be an automatic limitation that would prevent marking a question as a dup of a future one, but there isn't.

One solution would be to just, vote to leave it open with a comment explaining why, then mark the other as a duplicate of the older one. However, in this case it cannot be done because the older question doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer. I simply left a [comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49118/freestyle-animation-has-delay-in-cycles#comment143091_49118) on the other one linking back, but I have had debate about a [similar incident in the past](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/49857/2016/12/9).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes** you can mark any question as a duplicate of a newer question.

There are no time based constraints on what question is the duplicate.

There is one simple rule:

> Always direct users to the best possible information.

If a newer question/answer is undetected as a dup long enough to become better, then I will close the older one as a dup of this one.

So for example (and this was a real case) someone asked about z-fighting. It is an ok question, and there are nothing spectacular about the answers. Now about a year later "the" Z fighting question got asked. This is the question we link all z fighting question to, because it is better. To end the story, last year the older question got closed as a dup of the future z fighting question.

Robert Cartaino's answer ([Should duplicates be closed to the oldest question or the "best" question?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/506/2217)) talks about this very issue in a bit more detail.

---

In short, you should not be looking at the time stamp to determine which to close.